# jquery return false not stopping form submit in python

Tags: javascript, jquery

> My purpose is to stop submitting form if no attachment is attached.

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
$('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
    if ($('input[name="attach_document"]')[0].value == "" ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("No File Attached");
        return false;
    }
 });
});
```

Please help me to find why the code doesnot work.
Thanks

Comment: removed the Python tag - this has nothing to do with Python.

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting the form always, put `e.preventDefault()` before if statement like so:

```js
$(document).ready ( function () {
    $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        if ($('input[name="attach_document"]')[0].value == "" ) {
            alert("No File Attached");
        }
        else $('form').trigger("submit")
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<form>
Your input: <br>
<input name="attach_document" type="text" />
<button type="submit">Click </button>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: @hai_v Take a look on my updated answer, tell me if still doesnt work and wich type of input it is

Comment: @SilverSurfer..Thanks for your help but it doesnot work.I am using this code in frappe.so it is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function () {
    $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('input[name="attach_document"]')[0].files.length === 0 ) 
        {
            alert("No File Attached");
            return false;
        }else{
           $(this).trigger('submit');
        }
     });
    });
```